# Android Studio 0.4.2 Error [ ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html ]

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

This message keeps appearing in Android Studio's event log:

> ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
>              Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
>              getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
>              vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
>              StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false: ContentElementType: FILE; file: HtmlFile:incognito_mode_start_page.html
>              Boolean.TRUE.equals(getUserData(BUILDING_STUB)) = false
>              getTreeElement() = Element(FILE)
>              vFile instanceof VirtualFileWithId = true
>              StubUpdatingIndex.canHaveStub(vFile) = false

Anyone experience this or have any idea what it means?
I am using Android Studio 0.4.2

Comment: Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and in opened dialog select Invalidate and Restart. Check if it solves the problem.

Comment: @pyus13 yeah, thanks. Is there anyway you can give a brief explanation about this or maybe a link to some documentation? thanks in advance!

Comment: if your problem got solved using this than let me know so i can write it in answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bug reported in Studio 0.2.3 long back

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60576

Try this

**`Go to File > Invalidate Caches/Restart and in opened dialog select Invalidate and Restart.`**

If it solves your problem.